# Discrete math counting.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $A = \{1000,1001,1002,\dots,9999\}$

How many numbers in $A$ have the property that the sum of it's digits is even.

How many numbers in $A$ have the property that the digits appear in increasing order? 
That is the first digit is smaller than the second and so on. Example 1234.

Comment: For the even sum question. I know that the sum is 2 * k ( k is some integer). I however am not sure how to count these. For the increasing orders, i'm baffled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever you choose for the first three digits, there are $10$ choices for the last digit; half of them make the sum even, half make it odd. So exactly half of the numbers in the range $1000,\dots,9999$ have an even digital sum; that's $(9999-999)/2)=4500$.

The number of ways to choose a set of $4$ digits from the set $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ is $\binom94$, and there is just one way to arrange the chosen digits in increasing order, so the answer to the second question is $\binom94\cdot1=126$.

This assumes that the digits have to be in **strictly** increasing order, i.e. the number of ways to choose $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ from $\{1,2,\dots,9\}$ satisfying $x_1\lt x_2\lt x_3\lt x_4$ is $\binom94=126.$ On the other hand, the number of ways to choose $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ from $\{1,2,\dots,9\}$ satisfying $x_1\le x_2\le x_3\le x_4$ is the same as the number of ways to choose $u_1,u_2,u_3,u_4$ from $\{1,2,\dots,12\}$ satisfying $u_1\lt u_2\lt u_3\lt u_4$ which is $\binom{12}4=495$; this can be seen from the change of variable $u_1=x_1,\,u_2=x_2+1,\,u_3=x_3+2,\,u_4=x_4+3$.

Comment: OK so I think I do not properly understand the (9 choose 4). This means that we can only 'select' each of the numbers only once? If this is true I totally get it!

Comment: @gillmor123 Does "smaller" mean "strictly smaller", or are numbers like $1123$ allowed?

Comment: The practice question I am studying states "The first digit is smaller than the second digit, the second digit is smaller than the third digit, and the third digit is smaller than the fourth digit." No numbers like 1123 are not allowed. I don't think.

Answer (score 0):

If the sum of digits is even, how many odd digits can the number have? Condition on whether the first digit is odd or even, etc.

For digits in increasing order, have you seen the Stars and Bars solution? Count the gaps between the digit values...

Comment: Hey bof. I totally understand 1C) now, the answer in recipe form would be 9*10*10*5 = 4500. Thanks!!!! I think I understand the second, but is it possible with the 9 choose 4 to pick 1,4,4,9? where the two fours would mess up the formula?

Comment: @gillmor123 If numbers with repeated digits are allowed, of course you get more of them, $\binom{12}4$ instead of $\binom94$. I'll add that to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

How many numbers in $A$ have the property that the sum of the digits is even:
For this think how many odd digits the numbers can have then think given the number of choices of odd and even digits, how many numbers between $1000$ and $9999$ you can create.

How many numbers in $A$ have the property that the digits appear in increasing order: For this, think how many choices are there for the first digit. Then once you have chosen that first digit, how many choices are there for the second, then the third, ... . How many total choices are there then?

Comment: So for the even question. Basically the first three numbers don't matter (they can be even or odd) the last number will determine if they are odd of even, therefore we can say that  even numbers at the end will determine the sum's even or odd status.